# How to prevent updateOne from automatically inserting { '$set': { _id: 'foobaa' } },?

Tags: mongodb

I just want to increase adActive.viewCnt by one.

This is my code

```
    let adActiveModel = require('../models/adActiveModel');
    let adActiveTable = mongoose.model('adActiveModel');

    // Increment of viewCnt 
    await adActiveTable.updateOne(
        { "_id" : adActiveTable._id },
        { $inc: { "viewCnt" : 1 } }
    );
```

But for some reason mongodb does this:

```
    Mongoose: adActive.updateOne({ _id: 's0171' }, { '$set': { _id: 's0171' } }, { '$inc': { viewCnt: 1 } })
```

This does not work, { '$set': { _id: 's0171' } } makes it not work
If I copy that line to S3T an execute it as is, nothing happens.
But if I remove { '$set': { _id: 's0171' } } and only execute

```
    db.adActive.updateOne({ _id: 's0171' }, 
    { '$inc': { viewCnt: 1 } })
```

Then it works fine.

Why do Mongoose insert { '$set': { _id: 's0171' } }

How do I prevent it?

Is there a better way to just increase one numeric field by 1?

Comment: What are you exporting from `'../models/adActiveModel'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to use `adActiveTable._id` for the update i'm going to assume, that `adActiveTable` is a Document rather than a Model. If we look at the [documentation for Document.prototype.updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-updateOne) it states

> Sends an updateOne command with **this document _id** as the query selector.

(emphasis mine)

Also we can see that the first parameter of `updateOne` is already the update document. This means that mongoose is interpreting `{ "_id" : adActiveTable._id }` as the update part of the call and in preprocessing adds a `$set` operator around it.

To fix this you can just leave out the first parameter of your call:

```js
await adActiveTable.updateOne(
        { $inc: { "viewCnt" : 1 } }
    );
```

If you dont have a Document already fetched you can use [Model.findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) or [Model.updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne) instead.

Comment: I thought updateOne could use { "_id" : adActiveTable._id } like a find for the record it wants to update.  Using your idea I need to FIRST do a find{{ "_id" : adActiveTable._id }} and then after do an updateOne.  Is there no way to do them both at once?

Comment: And adActiveTable is actually a model - let me add that to my queston 
let adActiveModel = require('../models/adActiveModel');
let adActiveTable = mongoose.model('adActiveModel');

Comment: What then is the type of `adActiveTable`? You're accessing its `_id` property like you already have a Document.

Comment: I changed  await adActiveTable.updateOne( to await adActiveModel.updateOne( and then it worked ?!?!  Strange... I guess it prefer the model to the document.  Anyway you did put me on the right track :)

Comment: The reason is that youre using a different `updateOne` now. I added the documentation to the anwer.